# Multi Includes Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, timeout

I am using EF 6.1.1 and I am trying pull back data using the LINQ query below. I could write this query by hand in less than 30 lines, but entity framework is doing it IN THOUSANDS. See the SQL below, am I missing something?

**LINQ**

```
_UserRepository
            .Query()
            .Include(a => a.PaymentSchedules)
            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages)
            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages.Select(c => c.Image.HomePageImage))  //<<< this causes 100+ joins
            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages.Select(i => i.Image.HoverOverImage)) //<<< this causes 100+ joins
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(a => a.PaymentSchedules.Any(p => p.Active == true && p.DatePaid > eighthOfMonth))
            .Where(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages.Any(prof => prof.CurrentImage == true))
            .Select(a => a.Profile)
            .OrderBy(a => a.Id) //require for using skip
            .Skip(skipInt)
            .Take(takeInt)
            .ToList();
```

**SQL**

**Stackoverflow won't even allow me to post the SQL because it is larger than 100K characters and contains over 200 left joins!!

Please help.

** Edited: copy paste fail.

Comment: Do the properties `[user].Profile.ProfileImages` and `[user].ProfileImages` both refer to the same `ProfileImage` data type?

Comment: Also, is the `ProfileImages` navigation property on the `[user]` model necessary?

Comment: I experienced a copy paste fail and I updated the code. There is no nav property on the user for ProfileImages. When I run the query without the last two includes it runs with maybe 30 lines of SQL. When I add them back, I get thousands of lines and hundreds of joins. -A

Comment: And if you remove the first ProfileImages. Just let this:

            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages) // remove this 
            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages.Select(c => c.Image.HomePageImage))  //<<< this causes 100+ joins
            .Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileImages.Select(i => i.Image.HoverOverImage)) //<<< this causes 100+ joins

The same problem happens?

Comment: I personally would just use prepare a number of smaller Queries to populate the Context rather than trying to do one mega Query with many includes. IE a main query to load profiles, then separate query to get their payment schedules and another to load their images. The context will recognise the graph if navigation properties are declared properly

Comment: Are you sure the includes are required? If lazy loading is enabled then requesting the values in the where clause should be enough to populate them. Also, I'm not 100%  sure but maybe having the includes after you have done the where and selecting would help a bit?

Answer (score -3):

EF is very powerful but i don't prefer it with very complex queries like this which contains many joins or includes, i prefer using Dapper (faster).

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Also, you can split query into smaller queries Ex: Get ProfileImages in separate query then PaymentSchedules ..